# Filtering object in Javascript react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, object, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure of data:
This is source code of my chats component: https://pastebin.com/JJQFQyHi
[image]

every chat has two members, I want to display other persons data profile_picture and username in my chat list. So i want to delete unnecessary data. I use firebase realtime database.
This is how i tried to rid off unnecessary data.

```
getChats = _userId => {
    let data;
    var readedData = firebase
      .database()
      .ref('chats')
      .orderByChild('members/' + _userId)
      .equalTo(true);
    readedData.once('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({ chats: snapshot.val() });
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.chats));
      data = snapshot.val();
      delete data._userId;
      delete data.members;
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

console log:

```
> {"-M4NzlagjmeFH7IR_Api": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": {"data":
> [Object]}, "members": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": true,
> "tempuser": true}, "tempuser": {"data": [Object]}},
> "-M4O-aIxt9w2iKuCDweN": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": {"data":
> [Object]}, "members": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": true,
> "tempuser": true}, "tempuser": {"data": [Object]}},
> "-M4Q05H1lEUIyWqLJyoQ": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": {"data":
> [Object]}, "members": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": true}},
> "-M649remSnfBLBuYJIXO": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": {"data":
> [Object]}, "members": {"lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": true,
> "tempuser": true}, "messages": {"-M64A0ydh-WJstJIFIr1": [Object],
> "-M66cLC6OjQhlyNN5uDq": [Object], "-M66eWivUodiVtHIkfGv": [Object]},
> "tempuser": {"data": [Object]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you refer call `snapshot.val()` you get an object as you have shown in the console log. This value is then assigned to `data`.

When you try to `delete` keys from this `data` object, Javascript tries to remove them from the top level of the object. Since there are no properties with the given names (`members` or `_userId`) at the top level, it fails to filter anything out.

If you need a list of `tempuser`s, you can build it using the `forEach` method of the `snapshot`.

```
readedData.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  const userData = [];
  snapshot.forEach((data) => {
    userData.push(data.tempuser)
  });

  console.log(userData); // this should contain the tempusers.
});
```